# Linking local custom .otf font to Cloudpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, font

I'm currently trying to work with adding custom fonts to my cloudpage but obviously you can't upload your own custom fonts. I downloaded the font on one of my local drive and tried to link it using @font-face while also using AMPScript Base64 encoding. It is an .otf file I am trying to link to from the landing page and I was wondering if there was an easy way to link the landing page or microsite to the local .otf file to get the details of it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't link to a file on your computer/local network. It has to be publicly accessible.

Answer (score 7):

I recently helped a client with this very issue.

There are additional file type uploads that can be enabled by SFMC Support, including `.svg`, `.otf`, `.eot`, `.ttf`, `.woff` and `.woff2`.

My case number was `#18228955` if you need it.

**20210421** -- This was enabled for Classic Content/Portfolio, which is now deprecated.  These font files are not supported in Content Builder, sadly.