# Marketing cloud custom font usage

Tags: marketing-cloud, emailmessage, font

Hi have the font file with otf extension.
 Can any one give me a clear steps to upload in marketing cloud and use this in email templates.

Comment: SF Support can enable font uploads into Content Builder: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/212437/5202

Comment: Using a custom font in an email would be difficult, because it relies on getting the font to the recipient's computer and I doubt that's an easy goal considering how drastically different email clients can be. Expect many recipients to not see the font.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Thank you so much I have looked into the info of ticket you mentioned, that was helpful.